# Product images are getting overlapped after clearing the cache and refreshing

Tags: caching

I have a single problem on my Shopify store website. Well, basically the title says it all - the product images are getting overlapped after clearing the cache and refreshing. But, load just fine after a second refresh. I know this is a broad question, but I digged into the problem and was unable to find a single thing wrong with the CSS. I just want to know, how is clearing the cache related to how the images will load? You think there is something wrong with the CSS, or JS, or even HTML? Any ideas? I am very desperate, any leads will be greatly appreciated. I don't even know where to look, I am just really stuck at this point. I can provide every detail that will make it easier to look for the issue. I just don't know what to provide for now.

[How they should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaQZQ.png)

[How they appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI1L5.png)

Comment: This really doesn't sound like a PHP problem to me.

Comment: I know caching was the first tag, but somehow it shows php. I edited tags now.